# О сочетании «сухая победа»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания, лексическая-сочетаемость

Из телевизионного репортажа о результатах выборов Президента России (буквально двадцать минут назад):
*Владимир Путин одержал **сухую победу**.*

Что имел в виду журналист? Правильно ли он выразился?
Значения прилагательного в БТС: [сухой](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42#:%7E:text=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%7C%20%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%7C%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B&text=%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%A5%D0%9E%D0%99%2C%20%2D%D0%B0%D1%8F,%3B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9.) (подходящего — не нашла).

Comment: по идее, "выиграть матч всухую" - фразеологизм, а сухая победа - это что-то новое, но в интернете много)

Comment: Спасибо всем за интерес к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы записала так: *Владимир Путин одержал **"сухую победу"**.*
Другими словам, это победа **с сухим счетом**,  и это значение **есть в словаре.**

Термин **спортивный**, здесь переносное значение. Так как результат Путина — 87,21% голосов, то приближенно можно считать 100 %. Это **очень убедительная** победа — вот что хотел сказать этот **журналист.** Оппоненты, **условно** говоря, не набрали **ни одного голоса**.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка

**СУХОЙ**, -ая, -ое; сух, -а, -о; суше. **12. Спорт.** Такой, при котором проигравший партию не набрал ни одного очка (о счёте в игре). **С. счёт**. С-ая ничья (при счёте "ноль-ноль").

**Для справок**

```
   В выборах президента России участвовали четыре 
   кандидата. От партии "Новые люди" баллотировался 
   вице-спикер Госдумы Владислав Даванков. 
   Действующий президент страны Владимир Путин был 
   зарегистрирован в качестве самовыдвиженца. Еще 
   одним участником предвыборной гонки стал лидер 
   ЛДПР Леонид Слуцкий. От КПРФ был выдвинут депутат 
   Госдумы Николай Харитонов.
   На втором месте - кандидат от КПРФ Николай 
   Харитонов с 4,28% голосов, на третьем и четвертом 
    - Владислав Даванков ("Новые люди") и Леонид 
     Слуцкий (ЛДПР) с 3,94% и 3,16% соответственно.
```

Comment: Мне *кажется*, что на письме брать в кавычки нужно только прилагательное ("сухую" победу), потому что победа ведь реальная, не переносная.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова А мне кажется, что вообще ничего не надо брать в кавычки: "термин" понятен всем. Может, в данном случае следовало бы сказать "почти"?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  А в реальности победы здесь НЕТ СОМНЕНИЙ, глагол одержал за пределами кавычек. Обозначена необычность сочетания "сухая победа". // Без кавычек фраза выглядит "неодетой". А так ее можно наполнить нужным смыслом. Что кому понятно? Обычно проигрывают с сухим счетом (по словарю). А здесь кандидат выиграл с сухим счетом. И это уже переносное значение. А с "почти" образность сказанного вообще пропадает.

Comment: @Sharon  Совсем непонятно... Сухой счёт -- это счёт в ОБЕ стороны. То есть такой, при котором проигравший партию не набрал ни одного очка или выигравший партию не пропустил ни одного очка, другими словами, повесил баранку сопернику. Мы не берём в кавычки все слова с переносным значением. // Сухую победу кандидат не одержал, поэтому я и предположил, что здесь уместно использовать "почти".

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Вы, редакторы,  не берете в кавычки?  Я правильно вас поняла? // Я это выражение в Сети вижу исключительно в спортивной теме.  А у нас не спортивная тема. Можно я их тогда оставлю? // О метафорах.  Пример. Наши мысли быстрее молнии. Можно сказать: почти быстрее молнии.  Это я о "пропавшей образности".

Comment: @Sharon  Оставляйте, хотя образность никуда не пропадает без кавычек. И я не редактор, я биолог :)) Мы -- это все. Неужели слова с переносным значением заключаются в кавычки?

Comment: Мы это все? Забавно! Говорят, современное общество нельзя считать монолитным, как это было раньше. // Кавычки многозначны, уважаемый редактор-биолог) Я могу подчеркнуть переносное значение. // А вообще-то мне просто не понравилась фраза без кавычек (самое первое впечатление),  Выглядит как-то обыденно, не торжественно.

Comment: @Sharon  Мне надо было добавить ***же***: *Мы же не берём в кавычки все слова с переносным значением*. // Обыденно -- наверно. В любом случае победа не была сухой.

Answer (score 1):

Это из спортлексикона. Спроецируйте на выборы: я не понимаю, кто там соперничал.

НО СОПЕРНИК НЕ ОТКРЫЛ СЧЁТ, НЕ ЗАБИЛ НИ МАЛЮСЕНЬКОГО ГОЛА! ПУТИН ОДИН И ВПЕРЕДИ!

"Сухая победа – это выигрыш команды при условии, что соперник не откроет счёт в поединке. Если противник забьёт гол и проиграет, то победа не считается сухой".

Есть и [в картинках](https://verybet.ru/vidy-stavok/suhaya-pobeda-da-net.html#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B,%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9.):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нацкорпус:

1. Сухая победа - одно единственное [употребление 2001 года корреспондентом "Известий" Тимуром Хикматовым](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkcqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJAoiCiAKA3JlcRIZChfRgdGD0YXQsNGPINC/0L7QsdC10LTQsDAB).
2. Сухой счет - есть, первое упоминание 1961 год. И "сухой счёт" - это изначально 6:0 в футболе, то есть именно про игровой счёт. А в переносном значении только в 1997 году встречается.

> Потом играл один на один с Волыновым и обыграл его с сухим счетом
> 6:0. Карманин.

3. **Всухую** - слово существующее с конца 19 века, причём его употребляли в значении "**не промочив горло**" - не выпив, например, за знакомство, не посидев за встречной трапезой, не встретившись лицом к лицу. То есть всухую значит, так и не встретившись по-настоящему, пройдя мимо кого-то стороной.

> Инстинкт. Так это и пошло с тех пор, обмен кивками. С каждым разом становилось все позднее и позднее для руки. Согласитесь, что поздоровавшись десять лет подряд **всухую**, неловко как-то, неприлично как-то, вдруг ни с того ни с сего — за руку. Так я и не узнала, какая у Брюсова ладонь. Цветаева. 1925.

> Она сама потрепала его по щеке и сказала: — Красавец мужчина!.. Знаю, что следовало бы нам закончить это рандеву честь честью, да стоит ли, голубчик? Право, лучше будет так, **всухую**, в память об ingenue саратовской труппы, о чистенькой барышне, жертве увлечения театральным искусством. Стало быть, у нее зазрение-то явилось, а не у него, даром что она была уже в винных парах и про своего ростовского купца говорила прямо как про безобразника, с которого брала деньги. Боборыкин. Василий Тёркин 1892.

Кто это придумал, не знаю, на педивикии есть такое:

> В хоккее с шайбой [**«сухой матч»**, так же называемый шатаут - **shutout**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87_(%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%81_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9)).

То есть это какой-то сленг. но у нас скорее всего его стали переводить как "сухая победа", или "сухой матч". Хотя даже тут не могут договориться и "сухой матч", как по мне, звучит не менее криво, чем "сухая игра", хотя если их объединить... мэил ру:

> - что значит "Сухая победа в матче"?(2013 год)
> - Это значит что команда противника не забила не одного гола, ну а вы забили.

В целом последнее определение совпадает с определением слова **shutout**.

И ещё мне вот режет слух, потому что фразеология в основном происходит путём употребления наречий или деепричастий, а не прилагательных, за редким исключением исконно русских, вроде - красная/красна девица. Ну и сýха победа - не скажешь.

Comment: А у вас были такие ситуации в жизни, когда вы проигрывали "всухую"?  (Какие ощущения при этом?)  Да и  можно ли так сказать?

Comment: Можно, но это с другого конца, всухую значит, что одна из сторон не оказала должного сопротивления. Наверное было) но сейчас прямо не вспомню.

Comment: И кстати: "Достаточно привести слова главного тренера команды Валерия Белоусова после окончания проигранного «всухую» полуфинала «мы выжали из серии все, что могли», чтобы охарактеризовать положение с хоккеем в его прошлогодней столице" Опять же "Известия", но другой журналист. Может у них редактор "сухой"?

Comment: В Нацкорпусе есть [ещё один пример](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkcqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJAoiCiAKA3JlcRIZChfRgdGD0YXQvtC5INC/0L7QsdC10LTRizAB): "...доказательство превосходства российского тенниса вышло очень убедительным, так как «сухой» победы над Испанией наша сборная добилась, выставив второй состав".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец наверное, но тем не менее случаи единичные и это что-то из неологизмов, а не литературное.